# R to Tableau integration of user defined function to represent curved lines

Tags: r, mapping, tableau-api

I'm at a basic learning level of both R and tableau. My aim is to create an interactive flow map  of students from different countries coming to Munich using tableau. I have created the curve map in R using 'gcintermediate' but now i'm unable to create the appropriate code for tableau in order to read my R code so that the data is represented similarly in Tableau.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

I have attached my R-code and also the calculated field script that i tried to create.

```
 #code for calculated field tableau.
 SCRIPT_REAL("library(maps)
 library(geosphere)
 setwd("/Users/satarupa/Desktop")
 getwd()
 lat_me <- .arg1
 lon_me <- .arg2
 i <- .arg3 
 Data <- read.csv("/Users/satarupa/Desktop/mapping project/Data_Trial.csv", header = TRUE)
 lat_me <- 48.1351
 lon_me <- 11.582
 for (i in 1:length(Data)) { 
   inter <- gcIntermediate(c(Data$Y[i], Data$X[i]), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd = TRUE)
   lines(inter, col= "red")}

 ")
```

## code in R.

```
run.Rserve()
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
setwd("/Users/satarupa/Desktop")
getwd()
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="green", bg="lightblue", mar=c(0,0,0,0))

Data <- read.csv("/Users/satarupa/Desktop/mapping project/Data_Trial.csv", header = TRUE)
lat_me <- .arg1
lon_me <- .arg2
i <- .arg3 
lat_me <- 48.1351
lon_me <- 11.582
for (i in 1:length(Data)) { 
  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(Data$Y[i], Data$X[i]), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd = TRUE)
  lines(inter, col= "red")}
```

I didn't call the map command, as i wanted tableau to use the calculated Lat, Long from the table.

This is how my data looks in R and i want a similar representation in tableau.[Image in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlQ7p.jpg)
Regards,
Satarupa.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For the R tag we ask that you make your example reproducible by sharing your data via `dput()`. Please also provide the Tableau workbook or the data from it in a reproducible format.

Comment: Have you passed the .arg1, .arg2, .arg3 parameters? And why are you reading the file from your local machine if the data is already connected in Tableau?

Comment: i'm unable to figure out how do i pass the parameters for my defined function.